# Move Azure SQL Database to new Azure Account

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to move a large 1TB Azure database (PAAS) to a new Azure account.  I am trying to use Export but that is going to result in a lot of downtime for the database.

Will upping the price tier currently P1 (DTU) improve export performance?

Comment: From the Azure Portal this took 10 hours on P1 tier

Answer (score 0):

Yes, upgrading the service tier may improve the import/export performance.

[image]

Refer the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import-export-hang) to get better understanding.

Alternatively, You can easily Import and Export the database from one SQL Server to another in the same or different Azure Account using SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS).

1. Connect to source Azure accounts in SSMS.

[image]

2. Right click on the source database and do **Tasks -> Export data tier application**

[image]

3. Save as a **.bacpac file to your local disk**
4. Now connect to destination Azure accounts in SSMS.
5. Right click on **Databases** and select **Import Data-tier Application**

[image]

6. Select **Import from local disk** and browse for the .bacpac file saved in step 3
7. Configure the database settings (give database name and other required settings)
8. Import the database

Comment: I can't see how this is the answer as it is essentially going to result in all the data/schema being passed to the machine running SSMS for compaction.

Comment: you can install SSMS on your local machine and then connect Azure SQL Server using SQL Authentication. In this way you can access your database and create .bacpac file.

Comment: I don't think you understood the original question. Export under the portal creates a bacpac file. However, it was taking 10 hours to produce.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the DTU part. updating my answer with required information.