# Attach Azure blob to SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to attach my Azure blob container to my SQL management studio so I can restore my database. I am not using Azure sql I have a standalone sql server 2018. Every time I go to click "select blob container" the program crashes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH9mr.png)

Comment: Can you connect to the container using any other method? i.e. Azure Storage Explorer? Through the Azure console?

Comment: yes, I can see the info in the file share on Azure and I was able to connect the file share through "attaching a network drive"

Comment: A file share is different to a blob storage account though.

Answer (score 0):

I have restored my database multiple times on Azure Storage account and it works fine for me every time.

Please make sure you have installed the SSMS correctly on your machine. If required, you can uninstall and re-install and then try the below steps on it.

1. Right click on **Database name -> Task -> Export Data-tier Application**

[image]

2. Choose **Save to Microsoft Azure -> Connect**

[image]

3. Select the **Subscription**. Select the **Storage account** and blob **container** where you want to restore the database.

[image]

4. Check the Summary and click on Finish. It will start exporting your database in blob storage account as .bacpac file.

[image]

You can confirm the file in your selected container.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so I tried your steps and when I go to select blob container it says "No blob container in selected storage account"

Comment: Do you have container created in storage account?

Comment: I was actually trying to import the data from Azure container, I noticed SSMS was not able to see the container  so I created a new one and uploaded the data to that container. I then followed your steps but chose "import" instead of export and it seems to be downloading BACPAC file to my database

Comment: What exactly we are trying to achieve here? So you need to do both, export and import database?

Comment: Check the answer on this similar kind of thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507378/move-azure-sql-database-to-new-azure-account