# DACPAC error if External tables and data sources present at source db

Tags: dacpac, sqlpackage, data-tier-applications, azure-synapse

Getting the following error on DACPAC deployment to Azure Synapse SQL Pools:

```
Error SQL72018: SqlExternalDataSource could not be imported but one or more of these objects exist in your source.
```

This has started since my colleagues created couple of external data sources and external tables in the source database. Do we have any resolution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

With the given information it's not clear which tool you have used to create the `dacpac`.

With my own experience if you Import/Export dacpac using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), all your external tables and temporary files includes in dacpac.

You can refer my answer on this SO thread [Move Azure SQL Database to new Azure Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507378/move-azure-sql-database-to-new-azure-account/70515930#70515930) on how to Export and Import databases using SSMS.

You can also refer this third-party tutorial: https://www.sqlshack.com/importing-a-bacpac-file-for-a-sql-database-using-ssms/